# How to solve GNOME power manager installation problem?

Tags: updates, gnome-power-manager

I installed my updates today and now I can't login due to a fault. After booting, the login screen and the message about installation fault for GNOME power manager appears. After logging in, the system returns to the login screen again with the error message. I tried to boot using older kernel versions, but the same error appears. How do I solve this problem?

The exact error message is:

> GNOME power management is not configured properly, and ask the Administrator to fix it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AU. Please post the exact error message.

Comment: When I do this it does not keyin my password , the screen remains as ' password : _ ' with the underscore flashing , and when I press 'enter' nd type my password it says " login incorrect ". What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you are probably getting is

```
Install Problem! The configuration defaults for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly. Please contact your computer administrator.
```

This likely happens after a release upgrade

To fix it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on the login screen and login with your username and password and type these commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

It should probably fix it. The error is most likely caused due to lack of space

---

<strike>If the above doesn't work, you can try chmodding /tmp to 0777.</strike>

```
chmod 0777 /tmp
```

[(source)](http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-boot-due-to-gnome-power-manager-error/)

Comment: The /tmp directory needs to be chmod 1777, not 0777.  Making it 0777 is a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

its all bcoz ur hard drive space got over, just type ctrl+alt+f1 in login page
then type ur login name and password
then go to the desktop "cd Desktop"
delete some directories "rm -rf "directory name" " 
then restart.......ubuntu will work normally.....

note:usually delete bigger files........

Comment: Was indeed a space issue. Cleaning up some files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When your drive is on which Ubuntu is running gets used up it generates Install Problem!

The configuration defaults for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly.   Please contact your computer administrator.

- Step 1 Ctrl + Alt + F1
- Step 2 Log in: e.g user and your password
- Step 3 check you directories to see which folder is using a lot of
  space e.g download
- Step 4 `rm -f -r /home/user/download`

With the above steps you will delete some folders or files and create space