# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS fails to recognize my laptop as laptop

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, laptop, power-management, indicator

This is probably going to sound like a rookie question, but I have never ever experienced such issue. I had Ubuntu 11.10 without Unity installed on my old laptop Thinkpad Z60m. Few days ago, I got notification that 12.04 LTS is outside and that I should upgrade. As it is my old laptop, with nothing important on, I decided to go for it. 
All fine and well. Except, now, Ubuntu behaves like I am not using a laptop. There is no battery indicator and I cannot enable it via Power settings (setting doesn't get stored). Also, power consumption is enormous, so it is now hardly usable running only on battery. Thing is 11.10 worked fine. Also, my battery held up to 3 hours.

So, I guess my question is, is there anything I can do to fix this, or do I need a reinstall?

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling yes, but see if any of the experts come up with anything first. Well thats unless you can't wait to experience the brilliance of Ubuntu 12.04!

Comment: I am all ears :). Reinstall is my last solution.

Comment: The missing battery indicator issue is discussed in http://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon. This also happened to me when I upgraded to 11.10 and it seems this issue is [back with 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/126717/62095). Good luck!

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125115/how-to-solve-gnome-power-manager-installation-problem

Comment: See, also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon

Comment: Those links would be even better, if they actually contained a solution. :)

Comment: You could try running with the live CD. If that is ok then it is likely that a re-install would fix it.  Also though that would imply that it would be possible to fix by changing some config file somewhere, if only you knew which one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps (maybe charger, battery problem). Found it on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOeSa7tPo_g). Kind of old and it is Dell. Your charger is not recognized by your BIOS. And if your computer does not see an original charger the battery will not charge at all. Can sort this out by removing this idiotic option from the BIOS. They will give you another charger or change your motherboard (useless) and this problem will appear again after your warranty has expired.

Another reason why this is happening could be because you broke the prong on your charger, that's why its not charging. You must fix or replace the charger. It has nothing to do with the Laptop or battery. I had the same problem. I just added a new prong and it worked fine. It only took me about 5 minutes to fix. Easy fix if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Which part of "it worked prior upgrade" was not clear?

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer a "clean install"  of the operating system as compared to upgrading an existing one.

My reason is this "that if there’s a hidden problem when you upgrade the hidden problem shows up."

So perhaps reinstall a fresh copy of Ubuntu.

Dont forget to save your data first.

Hope this is of help but others may have other ideas .